# Updating a "developer rejected" app: "No eligible applications were found"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm updating an existing app. I first uploaded a binary for the new version, but had to reject it; the status is now "Developer Rejected". However, I can't seem to upload a new binary. Both Application Uploader and Organizer say "No eligible applications were found", and in iTunes Connect, I can find no way (buttons, options, check boxes) to activate the system for a new binary.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. The "Ready to Upload Binary" graphic didn't load (I'm using Safari), which is why I couldn't find anywhere to click. It still doesn't show, but I can click it, so everything seems to be okay.

Comment: Oh wow, apple didn't test itunes connect in Safari?! I got the same issue, thanks for the not-so-obvious solution!